# How do I transition an object's attribute in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I would like to apply a transition, not on a d3 selection, but on a js Object.

Something like

```
var node = {
    x      : 0,
    y      : 0,
    radius : 100
};
d3.transition(node).duration(200).attr('radius', 200);
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: What do you mean by "JS object"?

Comment: Edited to explain. By 'js Object' I mean a typical `{ }`.

Comment: And how does the object relate to a DOM element? Are you using this data to create the element? There's no direct way to select elements based on data, I would recommend assigning an ID to the DOM element based on the data that you can select it by.

Comment: The thing is, I use the nodes in a d3 force layout, where the tick function updates a bunch of dom elements depending on the nodes' values. So nodes aren't linked to one DOM element each, but to a bunch (in this case the force layout links' lengths depend on the nodes' radii).

Comment: But presumably you can identify the DOM object corresponding to a datum?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Indeed I could, but I'd prefre if it were possible to achieve something like I descibed, since it would be much cleaner code.

Comment: As I've said, you can't select elements by data directly.